# year drop down options not showing up

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

[image]In `react-datepicker`, year drop down is not showing up, All the properties have been passed. But still year drop down menu is missing.

```
<DatePicker
  name={props.inputName}
  id={props.dateBoxId}
  placeholderText={props.placeholderText}
  autoComplete="off"
  dateFormat={props.dateFormat}
  selected={props.value}
  onChange={(e) => props.changeSelection(e, props.inputName)}
  timeInputLabel="Time:"
  disabled={props.disabled !== undefined ? props.disabled : false}
  showTimeInput={props.showTimeInput}
  minDate={subDays(new Date(), props.minDate)}
  maxDate={addDays(new Date(), props.maxDate)}
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }}
  showMonthDropdown
  showYearDropdown
  yearDropdownItemNumber={15}
  scrollableYearDropdown
/>;
```

Comment: year dropdown in blank show value in not showing

Comment: Could you please add a sandbox example for your problem, so we could have a better look at the issue?

Comment: What is the value of `props.minDate` and `props.maxDate`?

Comment: props.maxDate value is 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase `yearDropdownItemNumber` value upto 50.
May be reason is it's min and max date selected of current year and in year dropdown, it's showing 1997 and your current `yearDropdownItemNumber` value is only 15.

Comment: Already try it Not working

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you `minDate` and  `maxDate` lies in the current year and hence it does show any years in dropdown.

Change you `maxDate` to add few years ahead and you'll see the years in dropdown list

OR

you can set your `showYearDropdown` to conditionalize

in this case the year dropdown is empty

```js
// Don't show year dropdown when maxDate year equal current year.

showYearDropdown={!maxDate ? true : moment(maxDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').year() !== moment().year()}
```

P.S: i am using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to check years for dates